# Get Image URL From String

Tags: c++, regex, qt, qregexp

I am trying to figure out a way to get a image url from a web page source.
I can get the web page source into a string and parse it line by line to find the line with the URL.
However, I haven't been able to figure out a good way to pull just the URL from the line.
I'm think this can be done with QRegExp, but have been unable to figure out how to use it.

Line I am trying to parse

```
<img width="980" height="1515" id="mainImg" src="//test/123.jpg" alt="test">
```

Final Working Code

```
void MainWindow::on_btnDownload_clicked()
{
QString url = "http://test.foo.com";

QUrl qURL = url;

QNetworkAccessManager manager;
QNetworkReply *response = manager.get(QNetworkRequest(QUrl(url)));
QEventLoop event;
connect(response,SIGNAL(finished()),&event,SLOT(quit()));
event.exec();
QString html = response->readAll();
QStringList str;
str = html.split("\n");
//qDebug() << url;

for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); ++i){
    if(str.at(i).contains("id=\"mainImg\"", Qt::CaseInsensitive)){
        QString pic;
        pic = str.at(i);
        pic = pic.remove(QRegExp("<img[^>]*src=['|\"]",  Qt::CaseInsensitive));
        pic = pic.remove(QString::fromStdString("//"), Qt::CaseInsensitive);
        pic = pic.remove('"');
        pic = pic.remove("'");
        pic = pic.remove('<');
        pic = pic.remove('>');
        pic = pic.remove(';');
        pic = pic.left(pic.length()-1);
        //qDebug() << str.at(i);
        qDebug() << pic;
    }
}


qDebug() << "Lines: " << str.size();
}
```

Comment: Have you considered QtWebKit?  It has the ability to access individual DOM elements and their attributes.

Comment: Try: `<img[^>]*src=['|\"](.*?)['|\"].*?>` http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d593ba673d914d9

Comment: @Brandon That did not work

Comment: can you include the specific line you are trying to parse in the question?

Comment: Added it to question

Comment: @Talon06 Brandon's solution worked for me with the line you provided. Can you post some more code?

Comment: Post the code I currently have I also tried copying the code form the link into QT creator but got errors that regex was not part of std

Comment: Print the actual line you found, in case it's not quite what you showed; an extra space for example will make the shown pattern fail.

Comment: I was able to get this working by shortening the regex so that it pulled the first part of what I need then removing the rest with multiple remove commands not the most elegant but its working.

Comment: :S It works for `std::regex`: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/17d7d13be833741e and clearer with C++11's escaped strings: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0cbddcf69eadd14e I don't know if it doesn't work for QT or not. If it doesn't, I have no idea why because it should. Wish I was more familiar with QT..

Comment: Now might be a good time to stop and read up on automata theory.  HTML is a context-free language, and thus you will never be able to parse it completely with a regular expression.

Comment: Comments are not provided for answering questions!